# JMenuBar not appearing unless I put everything in a single class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenubar

I'm trying to make a frame with a MenuBar, but I can't make it show. I tried using `pack()` since it was suggested in similar questions but that makes my frame non-existent, I end up with just the upper window bar.

If I put everything in a single Class, it works; so I assume my problem is something basic about the Java structure.

Here's my JMenuBar Class:

```
package jpaintnet;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

public class JMenuBar extends JFrame implements MenuListener, ActionListener {

    JMenuBar mb;
    JMenu addImage, addObject, save;
    JMenuItem circle, rectangle, triangle, line;

    public JMenuBar() {

        mb = new JMenuBar();

        addObject = new JMenu("Add Object");
        mb.add(addObject);

        addImage = new JMenu("Add a new image");
        mb.add(addImage);

        save = new JMenu("save");
        mb.add(save);


        circle = new JMenuItem("Create a circle");
        circle.addActionListener(this);
        addObject.add(circle);

        rectangle = new JMenuItem("Create a rectangle");
        rectangle.addActionListener(this);
        addObject.add(rectangle);

        triangle = new JMenuItem("Create a triangle");
        triangle.addActionListener(this);
        addObject.add(triangle);

        line = new JMenuItem("Create a line");
        line.addActionListener(this);
        addObject.add(line);
    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //here goes everything!
    }

    @Override
    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

My JFrame Class:

```
package jpaintnet;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame extends JFrame
{

    public Frame(String title) throws HeadlessException {

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        this.setBounds(100,100,640,480);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);

        this.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);
        this.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, mb);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And finally, my main:

```
package jpaintnet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame f = new Frame("JPaintNet");
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I've commented one of the `setVisible()`methods, but I ended up putting it again here just in case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are using the import javax.swing.JMenuBar and creating your own class called JMenuBar. You should never use duplicate class names. If you want a customized JMenuBar, you should be extending it and adding additional features there. Also, you don't need a new class for the JMenuBar in the first place to add items to it; all of that can be invoked on the JMenuBar object in your frame class.

Comment: `public class JMenuBar extends JFrame`  Well, that's a mistake to start with. Have you been through the examples from [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)? A menu bar belongs to a single frame, the rest of the content should then reside within that frame

Comment: @faris, thank you so much! I'll never do that again. You really helped me :).

Comment: @ClaudiaProvoste Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mistakes which you have made.

1. In your `Frame` class remove the following import

   ```
   import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
   ```

   because once you have imported `swing.JMenuBar` jvm will neglect the `JMenuBar` which you have created.
2. Your `JMenuBar` class should extend from `javax.swing.JMenuBar`, not from `JFrame`.

   ```
   public class JMenuBar extends javax.swing.JMenuBar implements MenuListener, ActionListener
   ```
3. Get rid of the `mb = new JMenuBar();` statement in your `JMenuBar` constructor. Because when you create a `new JMenuBar()` the first thing jvm does is call it's constructor. Creating another `new JMenuBar()` in side the constructor means you keep creating so many `JMenuBar`s, which will eventually result in a `StackOverFlow` error.
4. Remove the variable `mb` in your `JMenuBar` class and replace with `this`.

   ```
   this.add(addObject);
   this.add(addImage);
   this.add(save);
   ```

---

Then your window should work just fine.

[image]

---

**UPDATE :**

As [MadProgrammer has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250109/jmenubar-not-appearing-unless-i-put-everything-in-a-single-class/52250589#comment91450270_52250589), keep in mind to make your class names unique especially when it comes to libraries developed by java. And here's an addittional tip, avoid using java keywords as table or column names when creating databases. It'll save you alot of pain if you are to use frameworks like hibernate in the future.

Comment: Don't re-use existing class names if all possible, it's just confusing (yes I know the OP did, so lets get them to stop)

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew, have updated your code as provided below for your reference. Refer inline comments:

Here's your MyMenuBar i.e JMenuBar Class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

/*
 * 1. Renamed your class "JMenuBar" to "MyMenuBar" - do not use Java class names. Its bad practice
 * 2. Extend from JMenuBar class to create Menu Bar. Whereas JFrame requires to create a frame
 */
public class MyMenuBar extends JMenuBar implements MenuListener, ActionListener { 
  JMenu addImage, addObject, save;
  JMenuItem circle, rectangle, triangle, line;

  public MyMenuBar() {


      addObject = new JMenu("Add Object");
      add(addObject);

      addImage = new JMenu("Add a new image");
      add(addImage);

      save = new JMenu("save");
      add(save);


      circle = new JMenuItem("Create a circle");
      circle.addActionListener(this);
      addObject.add(circle);

      rectangle = new JMenuItem("Create a rectangle");
      rectangle.addActionListener(this);
      addObject.add(rectangle);

      triangle = new JMenuItem("Create a triangle");
      triangle.addActionListener(this);
      addObject.add(triangle);

      line = new JMenuItem("Create a line");
      line.addActionListener(this);
      addObject.add(line);
  }



  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     //here goes everything!
  }

  @Override
  public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
  }

  @Override
  public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
  }
}
```

Here's your MyFrame i.e Frame Class:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyFrame
  extends
  JFrame {

  public MyFrame( String title ) {
    MyMenuBar mb = new MyMenuBar();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    this.setBounds( 100, 100, 640, 480 );
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    this.setBackground( Color.white );

    this.getContentPane().add( BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel );
    // this.getContentPane().add( BorderLayout.NORTH, mb ); //Do not use this
    // method to set menu bar
    this.setJMenuBar( mb ); // this is ideal method to set menu bar

    this.setTitle( title ); // Missing as you have supplied title but missed to set it to frame
    this.setVisible( true );
  }

  // added main method here from your Main class
  public static void main( String[] args ) {

    MyFrame f = new MyFrame( "JPaintNet" );
    f.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

Will create window like:

[image]

I think that's what you want all together.